# Regex that blocks single digit numbers 2,3,4,5

Tags: java, regex

I am pretty new to regular expressions and for some particular case need a regular expression which will block numbers:

`2,3,4 and 5`

... out of:

`0 to 21`

Specifically, this should block only single digit 2,3,4 and 5 and not 12,13,14,15 or 21 and 22 for that matter.

I tried `[^\d2-5]` but then its also blocking 12,13,14,15,21,20,22 which is not desired since only 4 numbers specifically 2,3,4 and 5 are to be blocked.

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: Add your desired input and output examples for clarity. For instance, how long can the digit sequences be? What is the context?

Comment: Can you add some example full input strings? Are you passing strings that are just one number, e.g. "3" or "14", are they comma-separated lists like "3, 7, 11"...?

Comment: the desired result should be any number (no sequence just single number) between 0 and 21 but not 2,3,4 and 5

Comment: @Michelle: just one number and no sequence as such.

Comment: Why not parse it as an int and check that the value is <2 or >5?

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:xml]? Where does the XML come into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the range [0;21] excluding [2;5] range you can use the following:

```
^(?:[016789]|1\d|2[01])$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wV3hT1)**

If you just need to exclude [2;5] range, then the following might suit you:

```
^(?:[016789]|[1-9]\d+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qE4iQ7)**

Comment: You can write `6789` as `6-9` (bit in this case it doesn't really matter). Also I would probably replaced `^` and `$` with `\b` since we don't know if OP wants to test if sting is representing correct number or if regex should find interesting numbers within string.

Comment: This seems to be working fine, let me also try in my actual code base but looks it should work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pshemo OP stated in comments `just one number and no sequence as such`. For `6-9` - one symbol doesn't make difference, and I think that `016789` is more visually appealing than `016-9`.

Comment: Thanks I missed that comment. I also agree that `016789` is is OK here, that is why I said that it doesn't really matter if you use `016-9` since this will not change regex much, although I am more used to `a-z` form so `016-9` looks nicer for me (but that is personal preference and as some proverb in my country says "personal tastes shouldn't be discussed").

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try finding those specific digits by delimiting them with word boundaries.

For instance:

```
String singleDigitsToBeBlocked = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[2-5]\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(singleDigitsToBeBlocked);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Blocked: %s%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Blocked: 2
Blocked: 3
Blocked: 4
Blocked: 5
```

Comment: The only trouble here is the parser is not available to me. I have to just send the request to a third parser for which code is abstract to me. So i need to fix my regex itself.

Comment: @user3734081 That's a pretty significant piece of information that needs to be included in the actual question. Explain the actual problem you're trying to solve; why do you need to ignore 2, 3, 4, and 5 using a regular expression? How does the surrounding code work?

Answer (score 1):

what about just checking for patterns that include everything EXCEPT those single digits?

```
(\b[0-9]{2,})|([01])|([6-9])
```

[image: result of regex]

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple

```
(?:1[0-9]|2[0-1]|[0-1]|[6-9])
```

You can test this here: http://www.regexr.com/39044

Comment: Am I mistaken or effectively the same regex has already been posted http://stackoverflow.com/a/24185054/1393766?